# Why does multiple forms in jsp page causes spring to be confused

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC, and I found tutorials that made me do basic crud. However when I tried to do it on multiple forms in one jsp page, it doesn't work. Whenever I click on the "save" button on the anthropometric data form, it shows the illegalstateexception error for the "vitalsigns" model attribute. Whenever I click on the "save" button on the vital signs form, it shows the illegalstateexception error for the "anthropometricdata" model attribute. I don't get why spring is getting confused when I have the correct request mapping.

I tried adding the ("nameofmodelattribute") with all my ModelAttributes, and it still didn't help.

Although when I remove the other forms and leave only the anthropometric data form alone, it works. I can't seem to find out how this is happening.

This is the full error that shows:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/view/itr.jsp at line 10

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/view/itr.jsp at line 10

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/view/itr.jsp at line 10

7:  <table>
8:      <tr>
9:          <td>Height</td>
10:             <td><form:input path="height" /></td>
11:         </tr>
12:         <tr>
13:             <td>Weight</td>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:471)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.JspClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(JspClassLoaderFilter.java:47)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ForcePasswordChangeFilter.doFilter(ForcePasswordChangeFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilterChain.doFilter(ModuleFilterChain.java:72)
    org.openmrs.module.owa.filter.OwaFilter.doFilter(OwaFilter.java:64)
    org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilterChain.doFilter(ModuleFilterChain.java:70)
    org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilter.doFilter(ModuleFilter.java:54)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.OpenmrsFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenmrsFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'anthropometricdata' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.itr_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(itr_jsp.java:566)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.itr_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(itr_jsp.java:478)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.itr_jsp._jspService(itr_jsp.java:181)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.JspClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(JspClassLoaderFilter.java:47)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ForcePasswordChangeFilter.doFilter(ForcePasswordChangeFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilterChain.doFilter(ModuleFilterChain.java:72)
    org.openmrs.module.owa.filter.OwaFilter.doFilter(OwaFilter.java:64)
    org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilterChain.doFilter(ModuleFilterChain.java:70)
    org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilter.doFilter(ModuleFilter.java:54)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.OpenmrsFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenmrsFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

My JSP file:

```
<h1>Individual Treatment Record</h1>

<h3>Anthropometric Data</h3>
<form:form action="anthropometricdata.form" method="POST" modelAttribute="anthropometricdata">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Height</td>
            <td><form:input path="height" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Weight</td>
            <td><form:input path="weight" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body Mass Index</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Waist Circumference</td>
            <td><form:input path="waistCircumference" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hip Circumference</td>
            <td><form:input path="hipCircumference" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Waist-Hip Ratio</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Head Circumference</td>
            <td><form:input path="headCircumference" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chest Circumference</td>
            <td><form:input path="chestCircumference" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Save" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Height</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>Body Mass Index</th>
    <th>Waist Circumference</th>
    <th>Hip Circumference</th>
    <th>Waist-Hip Ratio</th>
    <th>Head Circumference</th>
    <th>Chest Circumference</th>
    <c:forEach items="${anthropometricdataList}" var="anthropometricdata">
        <tr>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.anthropometricDataId}</td>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.height}</td>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.weight}</td>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.bmi}</td>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.waistCircumference}</td>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.hipCircumference}</td>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.waistHipRatio}</td>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.headCircumference}</td>
            <td>${anthropometricdata.chestCircumference}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

<h3>Vital Signs</h3>

<form:form action="vitalsigns.form" method="POST" modelAttribute="vitalsigns">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Blood Pressure</td>
            <td><form:input path="bloodPressure" type="number"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Heart Rate</td>
            <td><form:input path="heartRate" type="number"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Respiratory Rate</td>
            <td><form:input path="respiratoryRate" type="number"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Body Temperature</td>
            <td><form:input path="bodyTemperature" type="number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Save" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Blood Pressure</th>
    <th>Heart Rate</th>
    <th>Respiratory Rate</th>
    <th>Body Temperature</th>
    <c:forEach items="${vitalsignsList}" var="vitalsigns">
        <tr>
            <td>${vitalsigns.vitalSignsId}</td>
            <td>${vitalsigns.bloodPressure}</td>
            <td>${vitalsigns.heartRate}</td>
            <td>${vitalsigns.respiratoryRate}</td>
            <td>${vitalsigns.bodyTemperature}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>

<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/view/module/chitscore/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

My Controller class:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openmrs.module.chitscore.model.AnthropometricData;
import org.openmrs.module.chitscore.model.VitalSigns;
import org.openmrs.module.chitscore.service.AnthropometricDataService;
import org.openmrs.module.chitscore.service.VitalSignsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class ITRController {
    @Autowired
    private AnthropometricDataService anthropometricDataService;
    @Autowired
    private VitalSignsService vitalSignsService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/patient/itr")
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map){
        AnthropometricData anthropometricData = new AnthropometricData();
        VitalSigns vitalSigns = new VitalSigns();
        map.put("anthropometricdata", anthropometricData);
        map.put("anthropometricdataList", anthropometricDataService.getAllAnthropometricData());
        map.put("vitalsigns", vitalSigns);
        map.put("vitalsignsList", vitalSignsService.getAllVitalSigns());
        return "itr";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/patient/anthropometricdata.form", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute("anthropometricdata") AnthropometricData anthropometricData, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
        AnthropometricData anthropometricDataResult = new AnthropometricData();
        switch(action.toLowerCase()){   //only in Java7 you can put String in switch
        case "save":
            Date timestamp = new Date();
            anthropometricData.setTimestamp(timestamp);
            anthropometricDataService.add(anthropometricData);
            anthropometricDataResult = anthropometricData;
            break;          
        }

        map.put("anthropometricdata", anthropometricDataResult);
        map.put("anthropometricdataList", anthropometricDataService.getAllAnthropometricData());
        return "itr";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/patient/vitalsigns.form", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute("vitalsigns") VitalSigns vitalSigns, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
        VitalSigns vitalSignsResult = new VitalSigns();
        switch(action.toLowerCase()){   //only in Java7 you can put String in switch
        case "save":
            Date timestamp = new Date();
            vitalSigns.setTimestamp(timestamp);
            vitalSignsService.add(vitalSigns);
            vitalSignsResult = vitalSigns;
            break;          
        }

        map.put("vitalsigns", vitalSignsResult);
        map.put("vitalsignsList", vitalSignsService.getAllVitalSigns());
        return "itr";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please no pastebins for stack traces and error messages.  Questions must be self-contained.  I fixed it this time.

Comment: I apologize. I thought it would be better that way. Thank you for changing it!

Comment: ok! you are using `POST` to get data from form, where is `GET` to bind data?

Comment: How do I use it? and is it really necessary, because when I use only one form, even without GET, saving to the database is successful.

Comment: you are missing `@modelAttribute` start here (http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial)

Comment: But I do have @ModelAttribute, and it works as long as I use only one form. However, when I add another form with a different model, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It is just because you have `<form:form action="anthropometricdata.form" method="POST" modelAttribute="anthropometricdata">
` mapped `antropometricdata` as binding result to itr jsp and sending `vitalsigns` instead...There is a same jsp mapping to two different commands..make it uniform or change the jsp's for any request and map accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank everyone who tried to help, but I have already found the problem.

When I click "save" in one form, it enters the doActions method, and within the doActions method the other models are not map.put inside it anymore just like it is seen in the setupForm method. This is what my controller class looks now:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openmrs.module.chitscore.model.AnthropometricData;
import org.openmrs.module.chitscore.model.VitalSigns;
import org.openmrs.module.chitscore.service.AnthropometricDataService;
import org.openmrs.module.chitscore.service.VitalSignsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class ITRController {
    @Autowired
    private AnthropometricDataService anthropometricDataService;
    @Autowired
    private VitalSignsService vitalSignsService;

    AnthropometricData anthropometricData = new AnthropometricData();
    VitalSigns vitalSigns = new VitalSigns();

    @RequestMapping(value="/patient/itr")
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map){
        map.put("anthropometricdata", anthropometricData);
        map.put("anthropometricdataList", anthropometricDataService.getAllAnthropometricData());
        map.put("vitalsigns", vitalSigns);
        map.put("vitalsignsList", vitalSignsService.getAllVitalSigns());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/patient/anthropometricdata.form", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute("anthropometricdata") AnthropometricData anthropometricData, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
        AnthropometricData anthropometricDataResult = new AnthropometricData();
        switch(action.toLowerCase()){   //only in Java7 you can put String in switch
        case "save":
            Date timestamp = new Date();
            anthropometricData.setTimestamp(timestamp);
            anthropometricDataService.add(anthropometricData);
            anthropometricDataResult = anthropometricData;
            break;          
        }

        map.put("anthropometricdata", anthropometricDataResult);
        map.put("anthropometricdataList", anthropometricDataService.getAllAnthropometricData());
        map.put("vitalsigns", vitalSigns);
        map.put("vitalsignsList", vitalSignsService.getAllVitalSigns());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/patient/vitalsigns.form", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute("vitalsigns") VitalSigns vitalSigns, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
        VitalSigns vitalSignsResult = new VitalSigns();
        switch(action.toLowerCase()){   //only in Java7 you can put String in switch
        case "save":
            Date timestamp = new Date();
            vitalSigns.setTimestamp(timestamp);
            vitalSignsService.add(vitalSigns);
            vitalSignsResult = vitalSigns;
            break;          
        }

        map.put("vitalsigns", vitalSignsResult);
        map.put("vitalsignsList", vitalSignsService.getAllVitalSigns());
        map.put("anthropometricdata", anthropometricData);
        map.put("anthropometricdataList", anthropometricDataService.getAllAnthropometricData());
    }
```